# While checking whether the user exists in the database “The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context”

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

While checking whether the user exists in the database, this happens "The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context".

"Sorry for my bad english"

This my Context:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{

    public UserContext() :
    base("PracticeDB")
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

View model:

```
        namespace Models.Models
    {
        public class LoginModel
        {
            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
namespace Models.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = null;
                using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
                {
                    user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == model.Name && u.Password == model.Password);

                }
                if (user != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Name, true);
                    return RedirectToAction("Users");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пользователя с таким логином и паролем нет");
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etwDE.png)

Comment: Clean, Rebuild your solution and see

Comment: Also make sure you actually create a migration and update database.

Answer (score 0):

User is a predefined keyword.So you can not use it here. You can use below code to check valid user.

```
            var Valid = False;
            using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
            {
                Valid = db.Users.Any(u => u.Name == model.Name && u.Password== model.Password);

            }
            if (Valid)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Name, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Users");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Пользователя с таким логином и паролем нет");
            }
```